# python 3 Call child attribute from parent method

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, methods, attributes, parent

Can't call child attribute in parent method, here's the test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class A():
    def getPath(self):
        return self.__path

class B(A):

    def __init__( self, name, path):
        self.__name = name
        self.__path = path

instance = B('test', '/home/test/Projects')

print(instance.getPath())
```

Running python test file `$ ./test.py` returns

```
./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(instance.getPath())
  File "./test.py", line 6, in getPath
    return self.__path
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_A__path'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this because you are using a private attribute.  If you do it using a non-private attributes, it will succeed.

Private attributes in Python are designed to allow each class to have its own private copy of a variable without that variable being overridden by subclasses.  So in B, __path means _B__path, and in A, __path means __A_path.  This is exactly how Python is intended to work.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private

Since want A to be able to access __path, you should not use double-underscores.  Instead, you can use a single underscore, which is a convention to indicate that a variable is private, without actually enforcing it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class A():
    def getPath(self):
        return self._path

class B(A):

    def __init__( self, name, path):
        self.__name = name
        self._path = path

instance = B('test', '/home/test/Projects')

print(instance.getPath())

$ ./test.py
/home/test/Projects
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `__path` unless you know why you need it. `_path` is sufficient to mark it as "private". However, `A.getPath` should not be trying to return anything that that isn't defined in `A` itself. Instead, call `A.__init__` from `B.__init__` to ensure any `A`-specific initialization is done correctly:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path = path

    def get_path(self):
        return self._path

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, name, path):
        super().__init__(path)
        self._name = name

instance = B('test', '/home/test/Projects')

print(instance.get_path())
```

Now that `_path` is properly isolated to `A`, you *could* switch back to `__path` if, for example, you were concerned about a child class adding its own `_path` attribute.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.__path = path

    def get_path(self):
        return self.__path

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name, path):
        super().__init__(path)
        self._name = name
        self._path = "foo"

 instance = B('test', '/home/test/Projects')

 print("{}, not {}".format(instance.get_path(), instance._path))
```

Comment: There are cases where it's entirely valid to use members in A that are not defined in it.  This is the "template method" design pattern.  The idea is that the base class implements the parts that do not vary, while subclasses implement the bits that do vary. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern